# Submit input type="date" in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, forms, date, spring-mvc

I want to submit an input of type "date" to a spring mvc Controller.
Unfortunately, I keep getting numerous errors. I'm new to spring mvc and especially to form submitting, not very clear to me why I need to have "commandName" in form.

My code so far:

backoffice.jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/getAllOnDate" commandName="date">
<table>
    <td><form:label path="date">Date</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input type="date" path="date"/></td>
    <input type="submit" value="View all on date"/>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/backoffice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String backofficeHome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("date", new Date());

    return "backoffice";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllOnDate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAllReservationsForRestaurantOnDate(@ModelAttribute("date") Date date, Model model) {
   LOG.info(date.toString());
   return "anotherPage";
}
```

Comment: just use RequestParam instead of ModelAttribute

Comment: @Rajesh I think "View API"-based solution (JSTL + Model) is requested

Answer (score 3):

You have to use @InitBinder in your controller ot bind the date directly :

> Spring automatically binds simple data (Strings, int, float, etc.)
>   into properties of your command bean. However, what happens when the
>   data is more complex for example, what happens when you want to
>   capture a String in “Jan 20, 1990” format and have Spring create a
>   Date object from it as part of the binding operation. For this work,
>   you need to inform Spring Web MVC to use PropertyEditor instances as
>   part of the binding process :

```
@InitBinder
public void bindingPreparation(WebDataBinder binder) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, YYYY");
  CustomDateEditor orderDateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, orderDateEditor);
}
```

Now you can get the parsed date directly in your method formated as **"MMM d, YYYY" :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllOnDate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAllReservationsForRestaurantOnDate(@ModelAttribute("date") Date date, Model model) {
   LOG.info(date.toString());
   return "anotherPage";
}
```

Comment: Upper case YYYY is "[week year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year)", lowercase "yyyy" is calendar year - I think you want that